# nested forEach doesn't change its elements

Tags: javascript, mongodb

This is what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I get no error after I executed the script but no changes or whatsoever is being made.

This is my JSON Object that is stored in `doc`

```
{
"name":"aaa"
"test":[
           { "carl":[
                      "huh",
                      "two"
                    ]
           }
       ]
}
```

This is the script that I am running:

```
doc.test.forEach(function(emp){
      emp.carl.forEach(function(pass){
      pass="change";
      });
});
```

but no changes are being made or whatsoever, What is wrong?

Expected output: change all elements inside `carl` to `changed`. all `test` elements will contain a property `carl` that contains an array of string.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: oops I want to change all the element inside `carl` to `change`

Comment: Does every object in the `test` array have a property named `carl` or is there just one?

Comment: yes, there will be carl properlty. let me edit my question

Comment: `pass` just holds the values `"huh"` and `"two"`, it's not referencing the array item in `carl`.

Comment: Ohhhhh so `pass` is just the direct value?

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning a parameter to some value won't have any effect outside that function.

Instead, you should assign a property:

```
emp.carl.forEach(function(pass, i, arr){
  arr[i] = "change";
});
```

```js
var doc = {
  "name": "aaa",
  "test": [{
    "carl": [
      "huh",
      "two"
    ]
  }]
};
doc.test.forEach(function(emp) {
  emp.carl.forEach(function(pass, i, arr) {
    arr[i] = "change";
  });
});
console.log(doc);
```

Comment: This did it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you actually need to modify the object. Something like:

```
emp.carl.forEach(function(pass, i){
    emp.carl[i]="change";
});
```

Comment: Thanks but It wasn't changed.